# How can I display category select dropdown on frontend

Tags: magento2, category, multiselect-attribute

I want to add category select on frontend in a custom module how can I do that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Create a xml file which loads your Block and Phtml file.

For Example: custom_test_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">        
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Ui Multi Select</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Mital\Custom\Block\Test" name="ui_multiselect" template="test.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

2.) Now Create the respective Block and .phtml template.
Mital\Custom\Block\Test.php

```
<?php
    
    namespace Mital\Custom\Block;

    use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

    class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey
         */
        protected $formKey;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
         */
        protected $_scopeConfig;
        

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
         */
        protected $_urlBuilder;
    
        /**
         * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
         * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Model\PageLayout\Config\BuilderInterface $pageLayoutBuilder
         * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
         * @param array $data
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Model\PageLayout\Config\BuilderInterface $pageLayoutBuilder,
            \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
            array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
            $this->formKey = $context->getFormKey();
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }

        /**
         * Prepare layout
         *
         * @return this
         */
        public function _prepareLayout()
        {
            return parent::_prepareLayout();
        }
        
        public function getCategoriesTree()
        {
            $categories = $this->_objectManager->create(
                'Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options'
            )->toOptionArray();
            return json_encode($categories);
        }
    }
?>
```

In above Block file getCategoriesTree() Method loads the all Categories in array form. Its just
an example, you can pass your custom array to display in the field.

3.) Create the phtml template file.
Mital/Custom/view/frontend/templates/test.phtml

```
<form action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('multiselect/manage/save', ['_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure()]) ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"  data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <div class="field required">
            <label class="label"><?php echo __('Select Category') ?>:</label>
            <div data-bind="scope: 'customCategory'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <script type="text/x-magento-init">
                {
                    "*": {
                        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                            "components": {
                                "customCategory": {
                                    "component": "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select",
                                    "template" : "Mital_Custom/ui-select",
                                    "filterOptions": true,
                                    "levelsVisibility": "1",
                                    "multiple": true,
                                    "showCheckbox": true,
                                    "options": <?php echo $block->getCategoriesTree()?>
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

4). For Now let’s create the ui-select.html template which we have used in customCategory component.
Mital/Custom/view/frontend/web/template/ui-select.html

```
<!-- ko ifnot: disableLabel -->
<label class="admin__form-field-label" data-bind="attr: {for: uid}
">
    <span translate="label"></span>
</label>
<!-- /ko -->
<div class="admin__action-multiselect-wrap action-select-wrap" tabindex="0" data-bind="
attr: {
    id: uid
},
css: {
    _active: listVisible,
    'admin__action-multiselect-tree': isTree()
},
event: {
    focusin: onFocusIn,
    focusout: onFocusOut,
    keydown: keydownSwitcher
},
outerClick: outerClick.bind($data)
">
    <!-- ko ifnot: chipsEnabled -->
    <div class="action-select admin__action-multiselect" data-role="advanced-select" data-bind="
    css: {_active: multiselectFocus},
    click: function(data, event) {
        toggleListVisible(data, event)
    }
">
        <div class="admin__action-multiselect-text" data-role="selected-option" data-bind="text: setCaption()">
        </div>
        <!-- ko foreach: { data: getSelected(), as: 'option'}  -->
        <input type="hidden" name="category_id" data-bind="
            attr: {
                id: 'wk-cat-hide'+value,
                value: value
            }
        ">
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: chipsEnabled -->
    <div class="action-select admin__action-multiselect" data-role="advanced-select" data-bind="
    css: {_active: multiselectFocus},
    click: function(data, event) {
        toggleListVisible(data, event)
    }
">
        <div class="admin__action-multiselect-text" data-bind="
        visible: !hasData(),
        i18n: selectedPlaceholders.defaultPlaceholder
">
        </div>
        <!-- ko foreach: { data: getSelected(), as: 'option'}  -->
        <span class="admin__action-multiselect-crumb">
            <span data-bind="text: label">
            </span>
            <button class="action-close" type="button" data-action="remove-selected-item" tabindex="-1" data-bind="click: $parent.removeSelected.bind($parent, value)
        ">
                <span class="action-close-text" translate="'Close'"></span>
            </button>
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <div class="action-menu" data-bind="css: { _active: listVisible }
">
        <!-- ko if: filterOptions -->
        <div class="admin__action-multiselect-search-wrap">
            <input class="admin__control-text admin__action-multiselect-search" data-role="advanced-select-text" type="text" data-bind="
        event: {
            keydown: filterOptionsKeydown
        },
        attr: {id: uid+2},
        valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown',
        value: filterInputValue,
        hasFocus: filterOptionsFocus
        ">
            <label class="admin__action-multiselect-search-label" data-action="advanced-select-search" data-bind="attr: {for: uid+2}
    ">
            </label>
            <div if="itemsQuantity" data-bind="text: itemsQuantity" class="admin__action-multiselect-search-count">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <ul class="admin__action-multiselect-menu-inner _root" data-bind="
        event: {
            mousemove: function(data, event){onMousemove($data, event)}
        }
    ">
            <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option'}  -->
            <li class="admin__action-multiselect-menu-inner-item _root" data-bind="css: { _parent: $data.optgroup }" data-role="option-group">
                <div class="action-menu-item" data-bind="
                css: {
                    _selected: $parent.isSelected(option.value),
                    _hover: $parent.isHovered(option, $element),
                    _expended: $parent.getLevelVisibility($data),
                    _unclickable: $parent.isLabelDecoration($data),
                    _last: $parent.addLastElement($data),
                    '_with-checkbox': $parent.showCheckbox
                },
                click: function(data, event){
                    $parent.toggleOptionSelected($data, event);
                },
                clickBubble: false
        ">
                    <!-- ko if: $data.optgroup && $parent.showOpenLevelsActionIcon-->
                    <div class="admin__action-multiselect-dropdown" data-bind="
                    click: function(event){
                        $parent.openChildLevel($data, $element, event);
                    },
                    clickBubble: false
                 ">
                    </div>
                    <!-- /ko-->
                    <!--ko if: $parent.showCheckbox-->
                    <input class="admin__control-checkbox" type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" data-bind="attr: { 'checked': $parent.isSelected(option.value) }">
                    <!-- /ko-->
                    <label class="admin__action-multiselect-label">
                        <span data-bind="text: option.label"></span>
                        <span if="$parent.getPath(option)" class="admin__action-multiselect-item-path" data-bind="text: $parent.getPath(option)"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <!-- ko if: $data.optgroup -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: $parent.optgroupTmpl, data: {root: $parent, current: $data}} -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko-->
            </li>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </ul>
        <!-- ko if: $data.closeBtn -->
        <div class="admin__action-multiselect-actions-wrap">
            <button class="action-default" data-action="close-advanced-select" type="button" data-bind="click: outerClick">
                <span translate="closeBtnLabel"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I get the selected value in my controller. Any help